# How to allocate separate Console view for each external tool in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I configured two external tools in *Run|External Tools|External Tools Configurations...* Each time I run any of them the output goes to the same Console view and overwrites the output from the previous run. How can I configure these external tools so that each one has its own Console view?